# Nginx rewrite disabled? Can't do a simple rewrite

Tags: nginx

I've been having a lot of trouble with rewrite directives - nothing seemed to actually work, so I tried making the most basic rewrite sample that I could:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/a$ /test.html break;
    }
}
```

I was assuming this would return the contents of /var/www/html/test.html at http://localhost/a but it doesn't, it gives me a 404. Permissions on test.html are set correctly and it is accessible at http://localhost/test.html. I'm assuming rewriting is actually disabled - but I can't find anything like that in nginx.conf. The settings file above is the default in sites-available, and other than adding `rewrite_log on;` to the nginx.conf file everything is stock as distributed by the nginx 1.12.1 package in Ubuntu (17.10).

Logs provide no useful information and enabling rewrite logging has added no extra information to the logs. And yes, I've restarted nginx after each edit of the settings.

I've been trying all sorts of combinations, so at this point I'm just assuming rewrites aren't working/enabled? I'm totally confused here - ANY hints would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but changing `break` to `last` made it work. This is confusing to me, as with this configuration I wouldn't expect there to be any processing after the rewrite. This is a pretty fresh install and there's not actually anything else on it yet that I would think would be interfering - so there must be some reason for this? If anyone has a better answer I'll switch the accepted, but for now this 'worked'.